# CAGradientLayer not shown until table cell is redrawn iOS 7 only

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, cagradientlayer

On my root view controller, I have a UITableView that uses custom cells, where a UIImageView fills the bounds of the cell and has a CAGradientLayer added on top of it to create a transparent gradient. It works perfectly in iOS 8. However, in iOS 7, the cells initially don't show the CAGradientLayer. But if I scroll down to make a cell out of view, then scroll up again to come back in view so that it's redrawn, the CAGradientLayer appears. Any ideas how I can resolve this?

Below is the code I'm using in my custom cell:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    l = CAGradientLayer()
    l.frame = bandImageView.bounds
    l.colors = [UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0).CGColor, UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.2).CGColor, UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5).CGColor, UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.8).CGColor]
    bandImageView.layer.insertSublayer(l, atIndex: 0)
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    self.contentView.frame = self.bounds
    l.frame = bandImageView.bounds
}
```

And in my tableview:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell: HomeTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("HomeCell") as HomeTableViewCell
        cell.bandImageView.clipsToBounds = true
        let bandImage = bandArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.bandImageView.image = UIImage(named: bandImage)

        return cell
}
```

Comment: My current workaround is to reload the data .01 seconds after viewWillAppear() is called. There must be a better way.

Comment: Try adding an IBOutlet of your tableView and at the end of your awakefromnib do: tableview.reloadData() and replace tableview by the name that you gave your variable

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: In your cellForRowAtIndexPath replace let bandImage = bandArray[indexPath.row] by: if(indexPath.row < bandArray.count){
    let bandImage = bandArray[indexPath.row]
}

Comment: same error as before. crashing on the tableView.reloadData() line (where tableView is the name of my tableview outlet that I connected)

Comment: To create the IBOutlet did you go in your storyboard and ctrl+drag the tableView in your file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66288/discussion-between-clement-bisaillon-and-codeman).

Comment: yes of course. i'm not that much of a newbie. ;)

Comment: haha sorry can you show me more of your code like the IBOutlet and the new awakeFromNib function

Comment: Or try using viewDidLoad and not awakeFromNib

Comment: Yes viewDidLoad actually fixes the issue, but only if I call the reloadData() after a small delay (i.e. .01 seconds)